# Is there a way to request access to local iOS contacts from a website?

Tags: ios, permission, contacts

Is there an equivalent to requesting native iOS contact permissions that can be triggered on a mobile website, e.g. for the purpose of uploading contacts to a chatting app or social media for social discovery?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's possible by default from a web site with existing versions of iOS. For that you will need to have a native app as a helper, or the user will need to enable experimental features.

An API for Contacts information do exist for Javascript. However, it is not supported by default on iOS Safari. You can enable it like this:

1. Open the Settings app
2. Tap Safari
3. Tap Advanced (at the end of the list of settings)
4. Tap Experimental Features
5. Enable "Contact Picker API"

For future reference, you can track the state of the API on this link:

https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_navigator_contacts

Note that the Contacts API is currently available by default on Chrome for Android. There it was introduced with Chrome 80 in February of 2020.